# How to change map color by current zoom level with mapbox gl js?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

My question is about mapbox gl js.

How to change map `fill-color` by current zoom level?

The `fill-color` of this map has population growth rates by country, with a gradation from minimum to maximum. However, if the zoomed location has similar data, the `fill-color` difference becomes difficult to understand. So, I want to refer to the tile information according to the zoom level, get the country on the screen, and redraw it.

I searched a lot, but I couldn't figure out how to get the information on the screen. Please let me know if you have any information.

**Zoom Level: 1**

[image: Screen Shot]

**Zoom Level: 3**

[image: Screen Shot]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question initially asks:

> How to change map color by current zoom level with mapbox gl js?

For that, you use an expression like `'fill-color': ['interpolate', ['linear'], ['zoom'], ...]`

But what you want is something very different:

> However, if the zoomed location has similar data, the fill-color difference becomes difficult to understand. So, I want to refer to the tile information according to the zoom level, get the country on the screen, and redraw it.

It sounds like what you want is context-sensitive color scaling. That is, instead of a fixed scale of colors where dark green always means X and light green means Y, instead, dark is the lowest value in the current viewport and light is the highest value in the viewport.

This does not have anything to do with zoom.

The steps you need are:

1. Detect when the viewport has changed: `map.on("moveend", ...)`
2. Find what values exist within the viewport: `map.queryRenderedFeatures(...)`
3. Calculate a new expression based on those values.
4. Set the new expression: `map.setPaintProperty(...)`

Comment: Thank you. I think my question is solved by 2 (map.queryRenderedFeatures ( . . . ).